# Am I okay in being in this relationship?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, relationships

Assalamu-alaikum...

I'm 14 years old and I live in Bangladesh..
My family is not so strict about ISLAM and it's rullings...
more like they are into the Bangali Cultures..(such as Festival,Event,Programme which includes in appropiate Songs,Dance...etc)....

I used to perform in many School Cultural Programmes..as most of the time my family would encourage me to do so....
and I thought that THIS IS HOW WE LIVE AS NORMAL MUSLIMS....
I didn't used to Pray at all or even perform any islamic activities...
I used to litsen to music all day.....mainly I was drowned in so much worldly things...
at this time I knew something wasn't right , the way I've been living is not pleasing me from the inside...

then after some years like when i was in the first grade...
I saw a girl and somehow felt greatly attracted to her..
Let me tell you My school is a combined school so Boys and Girls used to study on a same room...
thats why I used to look with amaze at that girl...
[I didn't knew anything about Islam and As a muslim I'm ashamed of my that self.....]
I realised that I liked that girl...
after few years, on 2022... I was still living the same life and I had so many friends(Boy and Girl both)...
and with their help I confessed my feelings toward that girl...

I had to do this...because right now in our county relationships have become so common that people date several people at a time  and cheat with them whenever they want...
and  a boy like that , who dates a lot of girls and sometimes even commits ZINA....tried to get into a friendship or a relation with the girl i liked,
that's why to save her from a boy like that... I proposed her...
[I'm telling you again that, I didn't know any thing about Islam , not even what is right and what is wrong...]

After that she accepted my proposal and we started dating
as her parents were seriously strict, I only got to see her on school...
I felt that some things should not be done as I'm in a relation right now, I talked with her on the first day of our relationship that we would stay far away from things that might lead us to ZINA...
and to find more about it....I started looking on the Islamic Books and online websites....
I learnt about Islam more and more and then realised that GOING INTO RELATIONSHIP IS CONSIDERED HARAM...

but I was already on a relationship with that girl for about 4 months...
we obviously didn't touch,talked online or in a private place in which only 2 of us were..
we kept the distance and she was so supportive and agreed with whatever decision i took...
As I learnt more about Islam I told her to start covering up...
Alhamdulillah then she started to wear HIJAB...

and on our 1st year I talked with her mother and she happily accepted me as her future son-in-law
BY THE GRACE OF ALLAH...
I now know a lot about islam and still study more about it...
I try to pray the 5 prayers and sometimes even pray the TAHAZZUD ...
I try to read the quran everyday or weakly...
I'm trying my best as a muslim and improved myself from which I was back in those early times
ALHAMDULILLAH...

However ,
In our country, we can't marry until a boy is 21 years old and a girl is 18...because early marraige is restricted...that's why my girlfriend's mother told me to study well and get a decent job and to prepare myself for our marraige and continuosly practice the deen to earn good deeds...
Me and my girlfriend both have kept a promise that:-
#. No touching until marraige
#. Not doing something that may lead us to ZINA
#. Not spending alone time in private
#. No going out for date until marraige
#. Practice our deen as much we can
#. Pray to ALLAH for our marraige and safety from many things including ZINA

I HAVE TO WAIT UNTIL I'VE BECOME 21 AND HAVE DECENT JOB TO MARRY HER...
but am I okay with this type of relationship?